# Android Share Intent Facebook post wrong Thumbnails

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Currently i am working on an app where there is an option to share text from the app to different Social network like Google, Instagram,Facebook etc. All are working fine except facebook where it picks up wrong random thumbnails. The code for sharing is like below:

```
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();

            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            if (Preferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.pref_copyWithShareUrl_key), getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.pref_copyWithShareUrl_default)))
            {
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, verse.getText() + "\n\n" + "http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getPackageName());
                //shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, verse.getText() + "\n\n" + " https://market.android.com/search?q=pname:" + getPackageName());
            }
            else
            {
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, verse.getText());
            }
```

Currently the sharing look like this:

[image]

But what i want is to include my app launchers image icon to be shared only. How can i achieve that without affecting the other share option.
Thanks

Comment: for facebook and whats app u have to use packagename facebook:"com.facebook.katana" and for whatsapp:"com.whatsapp"

Comment: where to put that code, also what will be uri for the drawable ic_launcher

Comment: 1. You are not allowed to pre-fill the text part of a share for the user - they have to type in the text themselves. 2. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android: _“Note: If your app share links to the iTunes or Google Play stores, we do not post any images or descriptions that you specify in the share. Instead we post some app information we scrape from the app store directly with the Webcrawler. This may not include images.”_

Answer (score 0):

Use ShareLinkContent provided by facebook to share

Comment: how can i detect whether facebook has choosen, so that i can use ShareLinkContent instead of Intent Action Send?